# Product calculation by custom dimensions in Magento

Tags: magento

I already asked this question (like many before me) in the Magento 'How do I' forums and have not received any answers/ideas.

I want to create a customisable product (picture/mirror frames) by size (height/width) enabling the user to enter the size.

I have seen this done in another Magento site with the ability to select unit of measurement which is another [excellent feature](http://www.web-blinds.com/belmont-aubergine) I would like to use.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at custom options of an product. There is little documentation, but here you can determine attributes without fixed values like normal attributes have.

You can find the 'Custom options' tab while editing a product in the menubar at the left.

Comment: This only seems to address pre-defined options. 

I need the ability for customers to enter ANY value (height x width) and the price to dynamically change based on the total size in square cm.

Other users have achieved this (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51990/P30/) but the solution is no longer on the Magento forum.